# Why does the same algorithm work in Scala much slower than in C#? And how to make it faster?

Tags: c#, performance, scala, jvm

The algorithm creates all possible variants of the sequence from variants for each member of the sequence.

C# code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var arg = new List<List<int>>();
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
  {
    arg.Add(new List<int>());
    for (int j1 = i; j1 < i + 3; j1++)
    {
      //if (j1 != 5)
      arg[j].Add(j1);
    }
    i += 3;
  }
  List<Utils<int>.Variant<int>> b2 = new List<Utils<int>.Variant<int>>();
  //int[][] bN;

  var s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
  //for(int j = 0; j < 10;j++)
    b2 = Utils<int>.Produce2(arg);
  s.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

}


public class Variant<T>
{
  public T element;
  public Variant<T> previous;
}


public static List<Variant<T>> Produce2(List<List<T>> input)
{
  var ret = new List<Variant<T>>();
  foreach (var form in input)
  {
    var newRet = new List<Variant<T>>(ret.Count * form.Count);
    foreach (var el in form)
    {
      if (ret.Count == 0)
      {
        newRet.Add(new Variant<T>{ element = el, previous = null });
      }
      else
      {
        foreach (var variant in ret)
        {
          var buf = new Variant<T> { previous = variant, element = el };
          newRet.Add(buf);
        }
      }
    }
    ret = newRet;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Scala code :

```
object test {
def main() {
 var arg = new Array[Array[Int]](5)
 var i = 0
 var init = 0
 while (i<5)
 {
  var buf = new Array[Int](3)
  var j = 0
  while (j<3)
  {
   buf(j) = init
   init = init+1
   j = j + 1
  }
  arg(i)=buf
  i = i + 1
 }
 println("Hello, world!")
 val start = System.currentTimeMillis
 var res = Produce(arg)
 val stop = System.currentTimeMillis
 println(stop-start)
 /*for(list <- res)
  {
   for(el <- list)
    print(el+" ")
   println
  }*/
 println(res.length)
}

 def Produce[T](input:Array[Array[T]]):Array[Variant[T]]=
  {
   var ret = new Array[Variant[T]](1)
   for(val forms <- input)
   {
    if(forms!=null)
    {
     var newRet = new Array[Variant[T]](forms.length*ret.length)
     if(ret.length>0)
     {
      for(val prev <-ret)
       if(prev!=null)
       for(val el <-forms)
       {
        newRet = newRet:+new Variant[T](el,prev)
       }
     }
     else
     {
      for(val el <- forms)
        {
         newRet = newRet:+new Variant[T](el,null)
        }
     }
     ret = newRet
    }
   }
   return ret
  }


}

class Variant[T](var element:T, previous:Variant[T])
{
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow has syntax highlighting built in; if you have your original code, it'd look nicer if you just paste it into the editor, select it, then click the curly braces icon on the toolbar. Your code doesn't appear highlighted; I presume the `<font>` tag is stripped.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the C# List .add and the Scala Array :+ are not the same thing. The Array is created with N elements in scala (so you're extending it each time with :+ and paying the cost of copying and allocation). The List in C# is created empty, with capacity N, so no extension when you .add  you're just doing an O(1) operation.

Comment: And as a consequence, ret.length in your loop will always be > 0, so you're not doing the same thing in the Scala code as the C# code.

Comment: thou it would be nice not see your code rewritten with regards to comments/answers received with time measurements for a new code :)
then we'll see which language is "faster" :D yeah! :)

Comment: A note here -- someone _replaced_ the slower Scala code with a fast version, making this question at best meaningless and, at worst, deceiving. I have asked Kos to restore the original code or provide the new timing. Until such time as that happens, readers, beware!

Answer (score 20):

As others have said, the difference is in how you're using the collections.  `Array` in Scala is the same thing as Java's primitive array, `[]`, which is the same as C#'s primitive array `[]`.  Scala is clever enough to do what you ask (namely, copy the entire array with a new element on the end), but not so clever as to tell you that you'd be better off using a different collection.  For example, if you just change `Array` to `ArrayBuffer` it should be much faster (comparable to C#).

Actually, though, you'd be better off not using for loops at all.  One of the strengths of Scala's collections library is that you have a wide variety of powerful operations at your disposal.  In this case, you want to take every item from `forms` and convert it into a `Variant`.  That's what `map` does.

Also, your Scala code doesn't seem to actually work.

If you want all possible variants from each member, you really want to use recursion.  This implementation does what you say you want:

```
object test {
  def produce[T](input: Array[Array[T]], index: Int = 0): Array[List[T]] = {
    if (index >= input.length) Array()
    else if (index == input.length-1) input(index).map(elem => List(elem))
    else {
      produce(input, index+1).flatMap(variant => {
        input(index).map(elem => elem :: variant)
      })
    }
  }

  def main() {
    val arg = Array.tabulate(5,3)((i,j) => i*3+j)
    println("Hello, world!")
    val start = System.nanoTime
    var res = produce(arg)
    val stop = System.nanoTime
    println("Time elapsed (ms): " + (stop-start)/1000000L)
    println("Result length: " + res.length)
    println(res.deep)
  }
}
```

Let's unpack this a little.  First, we've replaced your entire construction of the initial variants with a single `tabulate` instruction.  `tabulate` takes a target size (5x3, here), and then a function that maps from the indices into that rectangle into the final value.

We've also made `produce` a recursive function.  (Normally we'd make it tail-recursive, but let's keep things as simple as we can for now.)  How do you generate all variants?  Well, all variants is clearly (every possibility at this position) + (all variants from later positions).  So we write that down recursively.

Note that if we build variants recursively like this, all the tails of the variants end up the same, which makes `List` a perfect data structure: it's a singly-linked immutable list, so instead of having to copy all those tails over and over again, we just point to them.

Now, how do we actually do the recursion?  Well, if there's no data at all, we had better return an empty array (i.e. if `index` is past the end of the array).  If we're on the *last* element of the array of variations, we basically want each element to turn into a list of length 1, so we use `map` to do exactly that (`elem => List(elem)`).  Finally, if we are not at the end, we get the results from the rest (which is `produce(input, index+1)`) and make variants with each element.

Let's take the inner loop first: `input(index).map(elem => elem :: variant)`.  This takes each element from variants in position `index` and sticks them onto an existing `variant`.  So this will give us a new batch of variants.  Fair enough, but where do we get the new variant from?  We produce it from the rest of the list: `produce(input, index+1)`, and then the only trick is that we need to use `flatMap`--this takes each element, produces a collection out of it, and glues all those collections together.

I encourage you to throw printlns in various places to see what's going on.

Finally, note that with your test size, it's actually an insigificant amount of work; you can't accurately measure that, even if you switch to using the more accurate `System.nanoTime` as I did.  You'd need something like `tabulate(12,3)` before it gets significant (500,000 variants produced).

Answer (score 4):

The :+ method of the Array (more precisely of ArrayOps) will always create a copy of the array. So instead of a constant time operation you have one that is more or less O(n).
You do it within nested cycles => your whole stuff will be an order of magnitude slower.

This way you more or less emulate an immutable data structure with a mutable one (which was not designed for it).

To fix it you can either use Array as a mutable data structure (but then try to avoid endless copying), or you can switch to a immutable one. I did not check your code very carefully, but the first bet is usually List, check the scaladoc of the various methods to see their performance behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

ret.length is not 0 all the time, right before return it is 243. The size of array should not be changed, and List in .net is an abstraction on top of array. BUT thank you for the point - problem was that I used :+ operator with array which as I understand caused implicit use of type LinkedList

Comment: now it works faster then .net version, listed before. I just use array as val - it is for immutability. And I guess there is no more coping.

Comment: Agreed, it's not zero all the time, it's > zero all the time (as it's measuring the allocated length, not the used one). So the condition ret.length > 0 is always true

Comment: Kos, `:+` doesn't cause "implicit use of linked list".  It reallocates the entire array each time with one extra element.  That's entirely different.

Comment: Andrew edited your original code to place an optimized code, which made the question incorrect -- it asks why the C# version is faster than the Scala version, but the Scala version is no longer slower! Could you please either restore the original Scala version and/or paste the timing for the _new_ version?