# Trouble Converting Lambda Expression to Delegate Because of "some return types"

Tags: c#, lambda, functional-programming

I'm writing a Linked List program in C# because I want to test how I feel about the language and I'm running into some serious difficulty. I'm trying to implement a Map method that functions like a Haskell map function (code below for both). However, I'm getting the error messages:

```
main.cs(43,66): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to `MainClass.LinkedList<U>'
main.cs(43,33): error CS1662: Cannot convert `lambda expression' to delegate type `System.Func<MainClass.LinkedList<U>>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

The relevant code in question:
Ideal Haskell code:

```
map :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
map (x:[]) f = (f x) : []
map (x:xs) f = (f x) : (map xs f)
```

C# code:

```
public class LinkedList<T> where T: class
   {
     public T first;
     public LinkedList<T> rest;

     public LinkedList(T x) {this.first = x;}

     public void Join(LinkedList<T> xs)
     {
       Do(this.rest, ()=>this.rest.Join(xs), ()=>Assign(ref this.rest, xs));  
     }

     public LinkedList<U> Map<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U: class
     {
       return DoR(this.rest, ()=>new LinkedList<U>(f(this.first)).Join(this.rest.Map(f)), ()=>new LinkedList<U>(f(this.first)));
     }

public static void Assign<T>(ref T a, T b)
{
  a = b;
}

public static U DoR<T, U>(T x, Func<U> f, Func<U> g)
{
  if (x!=null) {return f();}
  else {return g();}
}
public static void Do<T>(T x, Action f, Action g)
{
  if (x != null) {f();}
  else {g();}
}
```

While Assign, DoR (short for Do and Return), and Do seem like they're "code smell", they're what I came up with for trying to not write

```
if (x != null) {f();}
else {g();}
```

type statements (I'm used to patternmatching). If anybody has any better ideas, I'd love to know them, but mostly I'm concerned with the highlighted problem.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use C# as a functional language. While delegates and such make this possible, it's not the way C# is primarily used. If you want a functional programming .Net language, have you looked at F#?

Comment: You need to make `Join` return the resulting `LinkedList`.  That or change your lambda that you pass to `DoR` to capture the `LinkedList` in a variable, then call `Join` on it and finally return it.

Comment: It seems to me that what you're doing "misses the point" of C#. None of this is necessary with C#'s List object existing.

Comment: @itsme86 It's more of I don't like typing the same thing over and over (if you're talking about the static methods). While it's true that I learned those techniques from functional languages, I don't believe that this program is functional, in fact it seems very non-functional to me (in that there are many side effects). Is there something that you would recommend in place of if(x!=null) {f();} else {g();}?

Comment: @juharr Thanks! I'll go try that.

Comment: @JPG It's not necessary, it's just something I used to try to learn the language. I'm not trying to make something to use, I'm trying to make something to learn. I've heard lots of good things about C#, and I'd really like to have a good, go-to, static OOP language w/ functional support.

Comment: If you make your `LinkedList` implement `IEnumerable` or maybe `IList` then you'll get all the Linq functionality.

Comment: @juharr I'm just trying to implement everything on my own to try to learn. This isn't meant to be used.

Comment: @JackBrandt What I meant was, your code has a definite functional programming language smell to it. Compare your code to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/linkedlist-implementation) for example. The linked code is a more traditional C# application.

Comment: @itsme86 Ah, I understand. I just don't really like what I see as unnecessary typing.

Comment: Why do you have a `class` constraint on `T` in `LinkedList<T>`? It looks like `Map` can be written simply as `return new LinkedList<U>(f(first)) { rest = this.rest == null ? null : this.rest.Map(f) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your immediate problem: the basic issue here is that you're mixing and matching lambda expressions that have either `void` return type or an actual return type. This can be addressed by changing your `Join()` method so that it returns the list used to call `Join()`:

```
public LinkedList<T> Join(LinkedList<T> xs)
{
    Do(this.rest, () => this.rest.Join(xs), () => Assign(ref this.rest, xs));
    return this;
}
```

An alternative way would be to have a statement body lambda in the `Map<U>()` method that saves the new list to a variable and then returns that. But that adds a lot more code than just changing the `Join()` method, so it seems less preferable.

That said, you seem to be abusing C# a bit here. Just as when writing code in a functional language, one should really make an effort to write *real* functional code, in the manner idiomatic to that language, so too should one make an effort when writing C# code to write *real* imperative code, in the manner idiomatic to C#.

Yes, C# has some functional-like features in it, but they don't generally have the same power as the features found in real functional languages, and they are intended to allow C# programmers to get the low-hanging fruit of functional styles of code without having to switch languages. One particular thing also to be aware of is that lambda expressions generate a lot more code than normal C# imperative code.

Sticking to more idiomatic C# code, the data structure you're implementing above can be written much more concisely, and in a manner that creates much more efficient code. That would look something like this:

```
class LinkedList<T>
{
    public T first;
    public LinkedList<T> rest;

    public LinkedList(T x) { first = x; }

    public void Join(LinkedList<T> xs)
    {
        if (rest != null) rest.Join(xs);
        else rest = xs;
    }

    public LinkedList<U> Map<U>(Func<T, U> f) where U : class
    {
        LinkedList<U> result = new LinkedList<U>(f(first));

        if (rest != null) result.Join(rest.Map(f));

        return result;
    }
}
```

(For what it's worth, I don't see the point of the generic type constraint on your `Map<U>()` method. Why restrict it like that?)

Now, all that said, it seems to me that if you do want a functional-style linked-list implementation in C#, it would make sense to make it an immutable list. I'm not familiar with Haskell, but from my limited use of functional languages generally, I have the impression that immutability is a common feature in functional language data types, if not enforced 100% (e.g. XSL). So if trying to reimplement functional language constructs in C#, why not follow that paradigm?

See, for example, Eric Lippert's answer in [Efficient implementation of immutable (double) LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10045446). Or his excellent series of articles on immutability in C# (you can start here: [Immutability in C# Part One: Kinds of Immutability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/)), where you can get ideas for how to create various immutable collection types.

In browsing Stack Overflow for related posts, I found several that, while not directly applicable to your question, may still be of interest (I know I found them very interesting):

[how can I create a truly immutable doubly linked list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10757378)
[Immutable or not immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9009627)
[Doubly Linked List in a Purely Functional Programming Language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1844195)
[Why does the same algorithm work in Scala much slower than in C#? And how to make it faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5686071)
[Converting C# code to F# (if statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3120478)

I like that last one mainly for the way that in both the presentation of the question itself and the replies (answers and comments) help illustrate well why it's so important to avoid trying to just transliterate from one language to another, and instead to really try to become familiar with the way a language is designed to be used, and how common data structures and algorithms are represented in a given language, idiomatically.

**Addendum:**

Inspired by Eric Lippert's rough draft of an immutable list type, I wrote a different version that includes the `Join()` method, as well as the ability to add elements at the front and end of the list:

```
abstract class ImmutableList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public static readonly ImmutableList<T> Empty = new EmptyList();
    public abstract IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    public abstract ImmutableList<T> AddLast(T t);
    public abstract ImmutableList<T> InsertFirst(T t);

    public ImmutableList<T> Join(ImmutableList<T> tail)
    {
        return new List(this, tail);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    class EmptyList : ImmutableList<T>
    {
        public override ImmutableList<T> AddLast(T t)
        {
            return new LeafList(t);
        }

        public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield break;
        }

        public override ImmutableList<T> InsertFirst(T t)
        {
            return AddLast(t);
        }
    }

    abstract class NonEmptyList : ImmutableList<T>
    {
        public override ImmutableList<T> AddLast(T t)
        {
            return new List(this, new LeafList(t));
        }

        public override ImmutableList<T> InsertFirst(T t)
        {
            return new List(new LeafList(t), this);
        }
    }

    class LeafList : NonEmptyList
    {
        private readonly T _value;

        public LeafList(T t)
        {
            _value = t;
        }

        public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return _value;
        }
    }

    class List : NonEmptyList
    {
        private readonly ImmutableList<T> _head;
        private readonly ImmutableList<T> _tail;

        public List(ImmutableList<T> head, ImmutableList<T> tail)
        {
            _head = head;
            _tail = tail;
        }

        public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _head.Concat(_tail).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

The public API is a little different from Eric's. You enumerate it to access the elements. The implementation is different as well; using a binary tree was how I enabled the `Join()` method.

Note that with the interface `IEnumerable<T>` implemented, one way to implement the `Map<U>()` method is to not do it at all and instead just use the built-in `Enumerable.Select()`:

```
ImmutableList<T> list = ...; // whatever your list is
Func<T, U> map = ...; // whatever your projection is
IEnumerable<U> mapped = list.Select(map);
```

As long as the `map` function is relatively inexpensive, that would work fine. Any time `mapped` is enumerated, it will re-enumerate `list`, applying the `map` function. The `mapped` enumeration remains immutable, because it's based on the immutable `list` object.

There are probably other ways to do it (for that matter, I know of at least one other), but the above is what made the most sense to be conceptually.